# SDL adjust window size

Tags: c++, windows, sdl, sdl-2

I want SDL window size to stay within [working area (SPI_GETWORKAREA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724947(v=vs.85).aspx) of windows which excludes windows taskbar other panels.

The problem is that both [SDL_CreateWindow](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) and [SDL_SetWindowSize](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_SetWindowSize) set the client area of window, not the size including window borders. So when I set window size to fit on a small working area, the borders still go out of working area.

> **SDL_CreateWindow:** Use this function to set the size of a window's ***client area***.

Does SDL provide a way to set window size within working area? or how do I get border size of SDL window so that I can do that myself?

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need WinAPI to do that.

The size of window borders can be determined by [`SDL_GetWindowBordersSize()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowBordersSize), and the part of the display not occupied by taskbar should be returned by [`SDL_GetDisplayUsableBounds()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetDisplayUsableBounds).

With these functions, maintaining a proper window position (and maybe size) should be easy.

Comment: But `SDL_GetWindowBordersSize()` only works on X11, not Windows, so your first sentence is very wrong.

Comment: @MichelRouzic That's what the wiki says, yes, but did you try using it? It works for me on Windows.

Comment: That's what I get for believing the wiki. It does work, however it gives me 31, 8, 8, 8 which seems like too much on each side (seems to be the size of the resizing control but not the actual visual size).

Comment: @MichelRouzic I don't have a Win 10 machine on me to check, but on Win 7 the resize control has the same size as the visual border, and the function correctly outputs `27 8 8 8`. It gives a wrong answer on Win 10, it may warrant a bug report.

Comment: Good suggestion. I had a look at the code for `WIN_GetWindowBordersSize()` and it uses `GetWindowRect()` which MSDN claims includes the area of the window's drop shadow. When replacing that line with `DwmGetWindowAttribute(hwnd, DWMWA_EXTENDED_FRAME_BOUNDS, &rcWindow, sizeof(rcWindow));` I get 23 0 0 0 when the window is maximised and 31 1 1 1 when it's not, which seems visually correct. I filled a bug report: https://bugzilla.libsdl.org/show_bug.cgi?id=5302

Answer (score 3):

The only way I know of (SDL 1.2) is to first create a small window (2x2 pixels) and then check the total window size using the Windows API (GetWindowPlacement). Based on this, you can calculate the parameters necessary to get the window size you are looking for, and finally resize the window (MoveWindow).

I hope someone has a better solution, because this is a very ugly workaround.

Comment: I think you don't need to create 2x2 size window. If you are using Windows API anyway you can use `GetWindowPlacement` to get window coords, then `ClientToScreen` to get client area coords on screen. Doing math on these two will give the border sizes.

Comment: If you find a solution that creates the window with correct size straight off, without showing any temporary window first, please post your code.

Comment: To use WinAPI we do need to have window first. I couldn't find a way to do it with SDL alone.